# Automatically Importing Data From a Website in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to find a way to automatically update a big query table using this link: https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:1

This link is updated with new data every week and I want to be able to replace the Big Query table with this new data. I have researched that you can export spreadsheets to Big Query, but that is not a streamlined approach.

How would I go about submitting a script that imports the data and having that data be fed to Big Query?

Comment: I can access to the link ...what contain this link ??? ...

Comment: sorry I mean ...I cant access.... is a json data?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar It contains a txt file I just want to have the script pull data from that link every week and upload to google cloud automatically.

Comment: Can add your data in your question ...

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar the data is the link

Comment: it seems that you want to create a scheduled pipeline. There are many way you can orchestrate this depending on the technologies you want to use. Cloud composer for example might me quick and flexible. For something more robust you could simply use a cloud function triggered by cloud scheduler. In any case, you need a process that fetches data from an HTTP stream :)

Comment: @Pievis thank you. Would you be willing to post an answer that lays out steps for this?

Comment: @Pievis just to be clear though, how would the function be designed? Could it be designed in any way you want or is there a predetermined format? The docs are not very helpful in explaining this and there are no practical examples to go off of.

Comment: @DataScienceAcolyte there are some restrictions but in general they are very powerful :) the only "format" that you have to follow is that an event triggers a specific function.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a working script that parses the content of the URL and places the contents in BigQuery. Based on that I would recommend the following workflow:

- Upload the script as a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/). If your script isn't written in a compatible language (i.e. Python, Node, Go), you can use [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/) instead. Set the Cloud Function to be triggered by a Pub/Sub message. In this scenario, the content of your Pub/Sub message doesn't matter.
- Set up a [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) job to (a) run at 12am every Saturday (or whatever time you wish) and (b) send a dummy message to the Pub/Sub topic that your Cloud Function is subscribed to.

Comment: Please answer this question as I need further assistance. If you do so I will reward the bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556262/creating-a-data-pipeline-to-bigquery-using-cloud-functions-and-cloud-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a HTTP request to the page using a programming language like Python with the [Request library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), save the data into a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) Dataframe or a CSV file, and then using the [BigQuery libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/) you can push that data into a BigQuery table.

Comment: Yes I know that. I was asking about using the link as a way to automatically update the table every single week. Whether it be with python or any other process I do not care. I would just like to have a streamlined process and I do not know how to create it.

Comment: Based in what you mentioned there is no streamlined process, another option is to schedule a cURL command in [Cloud Shell][https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/] to save the data into a [Google Cloud Storage bucket][https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/] and then a [BigQuery Load Job][https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data] to load that data into your table.

Comment: Can you update your answer and show me what that would look like?

Comment: Please answer this question as I need further assistance. If you do so I will reward the bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556262/creating-a-data-pipeline-to-bigquery-using-cloud-functions-and-cloud-scheduler