# Creating a Data Pipeline to BigQuery Using Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to build a Data Pipeline that will download the data from this [website](https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:CONG:::) and push it to a BigQuery Table.

```
def OH_Data_Pipeline(trigger='Yes'):
    if trigger=='Yes':
        import pandas as pd
        import pandas_gbq
        import datetime
        schema=[{'name': 'SOS_VOTERID', 'type': 'STRING'},{'name': 'COUNTY_NUMBER', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'COUNTY_ID', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'LAST_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'FIRST_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'SUFFIX', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', 'type': 'DATE'}, 
            {'name': 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'type': 'DATE'}, {'name': 'VOTER_STATUS', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PARTY_AFFILIATION', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS1', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_SECONDARY_ADDR', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ZIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ZIP_PLUS4', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_POSTALCODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_ADDRESS1', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'MAILING_SECONDARY_ADDRESS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'MAILING_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_ZIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'MAILING_ZIP_PLUS4', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_COUNTRY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'MAILING_POSTAL_CODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CAREER_CENTER', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CITY_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'COUNTY_COURT_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CONGRESSIONAL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'COURT_OF_APPEALS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'EDU_SERVICE_CENTER_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'EXEMPTED_VILL_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'LIBRARY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'LOCAL_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MUNICIPAL_COURT_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRECINCT_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRECINCT_CODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'STATE_BOARD_OF_EDUCATION', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'STATE_REPRESENTATIVE_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'STATE_SENATE_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'TOWNSHIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'VILLAGE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'WARD', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_07_2000', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2000', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'SPECIAL_05_08_2001', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2001', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2002', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2002', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'SPECIAL_05_06_2003', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2003', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_02_2004', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_02_2004', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'SPECIAL_02_08_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_03_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2005', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'SPECIAL_02_07_2006', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_02_2006', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2006', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_08_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_11_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2007', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_11_06_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_12_11_2007', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_04_2008', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_10_14_2008', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2008', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_18_2008', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_05_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_08_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_15_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_29_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_03_2009', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_04_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_07_13_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_07_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_02_2010', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_03_2011', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2011', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2011', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_06_2012', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2012', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_10_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_10_01_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2013', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_06_2014', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2014', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_05_2015', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_15_2015', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_03_2015', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_15_2016', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_06_07_2016', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2016', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2016', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_02_2017', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_12_2017', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2017', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_08_2018', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_08_07_2018', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
            {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2018', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2019', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
            {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_10_2019', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2019', 'type': 'INT64'}]
        prim_list = ['PRIMARY-03/07/2000', 'SPECIAL-05/08/2001', 'PRIMARY-05/07/2002', 'SPECIAL-05/06/2003', 'PRIMARY-03/02/2004', 
                'SPECIAL-02/08/2005', 'PRIMARY-05/03/2005', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2005', 'SPECIAL-02/07/2006', 'PRIMARY-05/02/2006', 
                'PRIMARY-05/08/2007', 'PRIMARY-09/11/2007', 'PRIMARY-11/06/2007', 'PRIMARY-03/04/2008', 'PRIMARY-10/14/2008', 
                'PRIMARY-05/05/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/08/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/15/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/29/2009', 'PRIMARY-05/04/2010', 
                'PRIMARY-07/13/2010', 'PRIMARY-09/07/2010', 'PRIMARY-05/03/2011', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2011', 'PRIMARY-03/06/2012', 
                'PRIMARY-05/07/2013', 'PRIMARY-09/10/2013', 'PRIMARY-10/01/2013', 'PRIMARY-05/06/2014', 'PRIMARY-05/05/2015', 
                'PRIMARY-09/15/2015', 'PRIMARY-03/15/2016', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2016', 'PRIMARY-05/02/2017', 'PRIMARY-09/12/2017', 
                'PRIMARY-05/08/2018', 'PRIMARY-05/07/2019', 'PRIMARY-09/10/2019']
        prim_list = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in prim_list]
        gen_list = ['GENERAL-11/07/2000', 'GENERAL-11/06/2001', 'GENERAL-11/05/2002', 'GENERAL-11/04/2003', 'GENERAL-11/02/2004', 
               'GENERAL-11/08/2005', 'GENERAL-11/07/2006', 'GENERAL-11/06/2007', 'GENERAL-12/11/2007', 'GENERAL-11/04/2008', 
               'GENERAL-11/18/2008', 'GENERAL-11/03/2009', 'GENERAL-11/02/2010', 'GENERAL-11/08/2011', 'GENERAL-11/06/2012', 
               'GENERAL-11/05/2013', 'GENERAL-11/04/2014', 'GENERAL-11/03/2015', 'GENERAL-06/07/2016', 'GENERAL-11/08/2016', 
               'GENERAL-11/07/2017', 'GENERAL-08/07/2018', 'GENERAL-11/06/2018', 'GENERAL-11/05/2019']
        gen_list = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in gen_list]
        party_list = ['PARTY_AFFILIATION']
        df=[pd.read_csv('https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:{}'.format(88+f), encoding='Latin1', low_memory=False) for f in range(1, 17)]
        df=pd.concat(df)
        df.columns = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in df.columns]
        df['birth_year'] = df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-6]).astype(int)
        df['Age'] = now.year - df['birth_year']
        for f in prim_list:
            df.loc[df[f]=='D', f]='Democrat'
            df.loc[df[f]=='R', f]='Republican'
            df.loc[df[f]=='G', f]='Green'
            df.loc[df[f]=='E', f]='Reform'
            df.loc[df[f]=='L', f]='Libertarian'
            df.loc[df[f]=='C', f]='Constitution'
            df.loc[df[f]=='N', f]='Natural Law'
            df.loc[df[f]=='S', f]='Socialist'
            df.loc[df[f]=='X', f]='Without Affiliation'
            df.loc[(df[f]=='') | (df[f].isnull()==True) | (df[f]==0), f]='Not Voted'
        for f in party_list:
            df.loc[df[f]=='D', f]='Democrat'
            df.loc[df[f]=='R', f]='Republican'
            df.loc[df[f]=='G', f]='Green'
            df.loc[df[f]=='E', f]='Reform'
            df.loc[df[f]=='L', f]='Libertarian'
            df.loc[df[f]=='C', f]='Constitution'
            df.loc[df[f]=='N', f]='Natural Law'
            df.loc[df[f]=='S', f]='Socialist'
            df.loc[df[f]=='X', f]='Unaffiliated'
            df.loc[(df[f]=='') | (df[f].isnull()==True) | (df[f]==0), f]='Unaffiliated'
        for g in gen_list:  
            df.loc[(df[g]!='') & (df[g].isnull()!=True) & (df[g]!=0) & (df[g]!='NaN'), g]=1
            df.loc[(df[g]=='') | (df[g].isnull()==True) | (df[g]==0) | (df[g]=='NaN'), g]=0
        df[gen_list]=df[gen_list].astype(int)
        df[prim_list]=df[prim_list].astype(str)
        df[party_list]=df[party_list].astype(str)
        df.to_gbq(destination_table='Voterfile.OH_Voterfile', project_id='oh-data-pipeline', if_exists='replace', table_schema=schema, reauth=False)
    else:
        pass
```

The problem is after defining the function in cloud functions, I will run the script in cloud scheduler, it will say the function ran, but no data will show up in BigQuery.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the logs as well:`[
 {
   "insertId": "1idtfdbg5drzu63",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4",
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:39.949108697Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:39.949108697Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "k9f9cjg5ds4bft",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-06T05:00:00.271618Z"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:39.823311702Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:39.823311702Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1xnnrrug5g0c2qj",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:37.290359769Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:37.290359769Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "sv8ssdg5e3blni",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-06T05:00:00.183767Z",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:36.916739031Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T21:12:36.916739031Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "7i1kgtfutdv2s",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4",
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T19:37:07.201347795Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T19:37:07.201347795Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "19io9oog5fvqy42",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-06T05:00:00Z",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "location": "us-east4",
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T19:37:07.092810676Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T19:37:07.092810676Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1t7pz9vg5e70eo5",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.396767720Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.396767720Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1p23vr0g59sba7d",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.250018Z",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "location": "us-east4",
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.267802278Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.267802278Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1yi5eng4p1lgiq",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:26:15.268636308Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:26:15.268636308Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1u1dz02g41np17v",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.369545Z"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:26:15.133041426Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:26:15.133041426Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1gzxg1lg4qi1i28",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline"
   },
   "httpRequest": {
     "status": 200
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader",
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:22:41.388248918Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:22:41.388248918Z"
 },
 {
   "insertId": "1es7ag9g5bdguh5",
   "jsonPayload": {
     "targetType": "HTTP",
     "url": "https://us-central1-oh-data-pipeline.cloudfunctions.net/OH_Data_Pipeline",
     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptStarted",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-01T17:30:00.257483Z",
     "jobName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/locations/us-east4/jobs/OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
   },
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "oh-data-pipeline",
       "location": "us-east4",
       "job_id": "OH_Voterfile_Data_Loader"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-01-01T17:22:41.268121872Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "logName": "projects/oh-data-pipeline/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-01-01T17:22:41.268121872Z"
 }
]`

Can you please help me figure out why this is not working?

Comment: Can you check your logs (under the Logging section) to see if any errors or warnings were output by the Cloud Function?

Comment: @vinoaj As you can see, no real errors that I can see. Can you look into this and see what would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your script work outside a Cloud Function?

Comment: According to the documentation, when you call the function .to_gbq() you should define also the data frame which will be written on BigQuery. Therefore, it should be: `df.to_gbq(df, destination_table='Voterfile.OH_Voterfile', project_id='oh-data-pipeline', if_exists='replace', table_schema=schema, reauth=False) `, could you please try that and see if the data appears on BigQuery? Link: https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pandas_gbq.to_gbq

Comment: Could you please check if your script work outside the Cloud Function as guillaume suggested? I tried it and I think the problem might be caused by the website.

Comment: The script works outside of the function and pushes the data to bigquery

Comment: @ChristopherRodriguezConde so I don’t think that is the issue

Comment: How much time this script took to run in your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code, I received the following error message: `OH_Data_Pipeline() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given`

You should modify your function definition to follow the [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub) (I'm not sure what `trigger` is used for, so for now I'm just hardcoding it to `'Yes'`):

```
def OH_Data_Pipeline(event, context):
    trigger='Yes'
    ...
```

Also, make sure you have a `requirements.txt` file and it has the correct libraries specified:

```
pandas
pandas_gbq
datetime
```

After all of these changes, I then receive this error:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)>
```

There seems to be an issue with the SSL certificate for the domain you are trying to access. You will need to play around with `read_csv()` to allow working with the domain despite the concerns with its certificates.

Comment: I get this response after testing it: 

Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
OH_Data_Pipeline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Comment: Also, what is the event and what is the context? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Have you set your function to respond to a Pub/Sub event or another type of event? "event" & "context" are for handling Pub/Sub events

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little to run on my machine and also in Cloud Functions.

```
def main(arg):
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_gbq
    import datetime, io, requests
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    schema=[{'name': 'SOS_VOTERID', 'type': 'STRING'},{'name': 'COUNTY_NUMBER', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'COUNTY_ID', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'LAST_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'FIRST_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'SUFFIX', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', 'type': 'DATE'}, 
        {'name': 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'type': 'DATE'}, {'name': 'VOTER_STATUS', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PARTY_AFFILIATION', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS1', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_SECONDARY_ADDR', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ZIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_ZIP_PLUS4', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'RESIDENTIAL_POSTALCODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_ADDRESS1', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'MAILING_SECONDARY_ADDRESS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'MAILING_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_ZIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'MAILING_ZIP_PLUS4', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MAILING_COUNTRY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'MAILING_POSTAL_CODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CAREER_CENTER', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'CITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CITY_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'COUNTY_COURT_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'CONGRESSIONAL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'COURT_OF_APPEALS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'EDU_SERVICE_CENTER_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'EXEMPTED_VILL_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'LIBRARY', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'LOCAL_SCHOOL_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'MUNICIPAL_COURT_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRECINCT_NAME', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRECINCT_CODE', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'STATE_BOARD_OF_EDUCATION', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'STATE_REPRESENTATIVE_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'STATE_SENATE_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'TOWNSHIP', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'VILLAGE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'WARD', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_07_2000', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2000', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'SPECIAL_05_08_2001', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2001', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2002', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2002', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'SPECIAL_05_06_2003', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2003', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_02_2004', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_02_2004', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'SPECIAL_02_08_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_03_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2005', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2005', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'SPECIAL_02_07_2006', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_02_2006', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2006', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_08_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_11_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2007', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_11_06_2007', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_12_11_2007', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_04_2008', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_10_14_2008', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2008', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_18_2008', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_05_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_08_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_15_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_29_2009', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_03_2009', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_04_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_07_13_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_07_2010', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_02_2010', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_03_2011', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2011', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2011', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_06_2012', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2012', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_10_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_10_01_2013', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2013', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_06_2014', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_04_2014', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_05_2015', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_15_2015', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_03_2015', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_03_15_2016', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_06_07_2016', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_13_2016', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_08_2016', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_02_2017', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_12_2017', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_07_2017', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_08_2018', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_08_07_2018', 'type': 'INT64'}, 
        {'name': 'GENERAL_11_06_2018', 'type': 'INT64'}, {'name': 'PRIMARY_05_07_2019', 'type': 'STRING'}, 
        {'name': 'PRIMARY_09_10_2019', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'GENERAL_11_05_2019', 'type': 'INT64'}]
    prim_list = ['PRIMARY-03/07/2000', 'SPECIAL-05/08/2001', 'PRIMARY-05/07/2002', 'SPECIAL-05/06/2003', 'PRIMARY-03/02/2004', 
            'SPECIAL-02/08/2005', 'PRIMARY-05/03/2005', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2005', 'SPECIAL-02/07/2006', 'PRIMARY-05/02/2006', 
            'PRIMARY-05/08/2007', 'PRIMARY-09/11/2007', 'PRIMARY-11/06/2007', 'PRIMARY-03/04/2008', 'PRIMARY-10/14/2008', 
            'PRIMARY-05/05/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/08/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/15/2009', 'PRIMARY-09/29/2009', 'PRIMARY-05/04/2010', 
            'PRIMARY-07/13/2010', 'PRIMARY-09/07/2010', 'PRIMARY-05/03/2011', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2011', 'PRIMARY-03/06/2012', 
            'PRIMARY-05/07/2013', 'PRIMARY-09/10/2013', 'PRIMARY-10/01/2013', 'PRIMARY-05/06/2014', 'PRIMARY-05/05/2015', 
            'PRIMARY-09/15/2015', 'PRIMARY-03/15/2016', 'PRIMARY-09/13/2016', 'PRIMARY-05/02/2017', 'PRIMARY-09/12/2017', 
            'PRIMARY-05/08/2018', 'PRIMARY-05/07/2019', 'PRIMARY-09/10/2019']
    prim_list = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in prim_list]
    gen_list = ['GENERAL-11/07/2000', 'GENERAL-11/06/2001', 'GENERAL-11/05/2002', 'GENERAL-11/04/2003', 'GENERAL-11/02/2004', 
           'GENERAL-11/08/2005', 'GENERAL-11/07/2006', 'GENERAL-11/06/2007', 'GENERAL-12/11/2007', 'GENERAL-11/04/2008', 
           'GENERAL-11/18/2008', 'GENERAL-11/03/2009', 'GENERAL-11/02/2010', 'GENERAL-11/08/2011', 'GENERAL-11/06/2012', 
           'GENERAL-11/05/2013', 'GENERAL-11/04/2014', 'GENERAL-11/03/2015', 'GENERAL-06/07/2016', 'GENERAL-11/08/2016', 
           'GENERAL-11/07/2017', 'GENERAL-08/07/2018', 'GENERAL-11/06/2018', 'GENERAL-11/05/2019']
    gen_list = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in gen_list]
    party_list = ['PARTY_AFFILIATION']
    df= [pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(requests.get('https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:{}'.format(88+f), verify=False).text)),encoding='Latin1', low_memory=False) for f in range(1, 2) ]
    #df=[pd.read_csv('https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:{}'.format(88+f), encoding='Latin1', low_memory=False) for f in range(1, 17)]
    df=pd.concat(df)
    df.columns = [f.replace('-', '_').replace('/', '_') for f in df.columns]
    df['birth_year'] = df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-6]).astype(int)
    df['Age'] = datetime.datetime.now().year - df['birth_year']
    for f in prim_list:
        df.loc[df[f]=='D', f]='Democrat'
        df.loc[df[f]=='R', f]='Republican'
        df.loc[df[f]=='G', f]='Green'
        df.loc[df[f]=='E', f]='Reform'
        df.loc[df[f]=='L', f]='Libertarian'
        df.loc[df[f]=='C', f]='Constitution'
        df.loc[df[f]=='N', f]='Natural Law'
        df.loc[df[f]=='S', f]='Socialist'
        df.loc[df[f]=='X', f]='Without Affiliation'
        df.loc[(df[f]=='') | (df[f].isnull()==True) | (df[f]==0), f]='Not Voted'
    for f in party_list:
        df.loc[df[f]=='D', f]='Democrat'
        df.loc[df[f]=='R', f]='Republican'
        df.loc[df[f]=='G', f]='Green'
        df.loc[df[f]=='E', f]='Reform'
        df.loc[df[f]=='L', f]='Libertarian'
        df.loc[df[f]=='C', f]='Constitution'
        df.loc[df[f]=='N', f]='Natural Law'
        df.loc[df[f]=='S', f]='Socialist'
        df.loc[df[f]=='X', f]='Unaffiliated'
        df.loc[(df[f]=='') | (df[f].isnull()==True) | (df[f]==0), f]='Unaffiliated'
    for g in gen_list:  
        df.loc[(df[g]!='') & (df[g].isnull()!=True) & (df[g]!=0) & (df[g]!='NaN'), g]=1
        df.loc[(df[g]=='') | (df[g].isnull()==True) | (df[g]==0) | (df[g]=='NaN'), g]=0
    df[gen_list]=df[gen_list].astype(int)
    df[prim_list]=df[prim_list].astype(str)
    df[party_list]=df[party_list].astype(str)
    df.to_gbq(destination_table='Voterfile.OH_Voterfile', project_id='astute-acolyte-260912', if_exists='replace', table_schema=schema, reauth=False)
```

Notice that the `verify=False`is **ONLY** for testing proposes. It shall not be used in production. 
After running your code in my machine and in `Cloud Functions`, I realized two things:

1. Your code takes a long time to run since it needs to download and process files. Given that, it should be deployed in `Cloud Functions` because Cloud Functions has a maximum timeout of 9 minutes as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout)
2. To perform all this downloads and transformations, your code uses a lot of memory. I tried to run on Cloud Functions with the maximum possible amount of memory (2GB) and It reached the limit of the memory.

You could try using a VM in Compute Engine for that. In this case you could also use Cloud Schedule to turn on and turn off your VM in the exactly time you want. You can find the tutorial for that here

For creating a VM in Compute Engine, you can follow this tutorial [Creating an instance from a public image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage)

Keep in mind that when using VMs in Compute Engine, you will pay for the processing when the VM is turned on and for the storage of the VM`s disk both when the VM is turned on or off.
After creating the VM, you can access it through the console. You should prepare the enviroment for your code in the VM the same way you did in your local machine.

After having your enviroment configured and a deployable code, you can use [crontab](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) to schedule the execution of your script by the system.

Now we have the last step: configure a Cloud Schedule to turn on an turn off your VM in the righ time. You can find the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule). You should schedule your VM to turn on some minutes before the time you define in the crontab.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how I would run the script on the VM and provide screenshots for this process in your answer? I am completely new to this and the documentation is too vague.

Comment: I will not be able to reproduce the steps in the weekend. I`ll update my answer providing some links for good tutorials and advices

Comment: Just edited the post. I hope this is the answer you`re looking for